# Semiring that has unique factorization except zero

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

In a ring, there is unique factorization domain. Then is there a similar concept in semiring - that is a commutative semiring that has unique factorization for every element except zero? If so, what would be such semiring that has infinitely many prime elements?

Comment: Are you asking for a *characterization* of such unique factorization semirings? (One example is $\Bbb N$, naturally.)

Answer (score 0):

Well every UFD is already a semiring, but you are probably interested in an example that isn't a ring, so the obvious candidate is $\Bbb N=\{0,1,2,3,\ldots\}$.

If you are asking about what the definition of a unique factorization semiring would be, then I would say that the ring definition carries over pretty much word for word to semirings with no nonzero zero-divisors. The definition only makes reference to multiplication, after all.