# Unique Factorisation in Semirings

Tags: elementary-number-theory, ring-theory, algebraic-number-theory, unique-factorization-domains, semiring

$\mathbb{N}$ forms a [semiring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semiring) with unique factorization (by the fundamental theorem of arithmetic) and only one unit (namely $1$). In other words, it is what could be considered as the equivalent of a [UFD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unique_factorization_domain) for semirings (is there an established name for such an object?). I presume that not every semiring is a semiring UFD, so here is my question: apart from $\mathbb{N}[x]$, what other semirings have unique factorization and exactly one unit?

Comment: May as well write down $F_2$ while we're at it.

Comment: [Related](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/909046/29335)

Comment: [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1509.03354.pdf) I see them called "unique factorization semirings". In case you're wondering, the definition there requires the semiring to be multiplicatively cancellative, e.g. "a semiring domain." I thought someone would call it a "unique factorization semidomain" too, but I don't think I saw any hits like that.

Comment: @rschwieb what would be some examples beyond the obvious $\mathbb{N}$ and $\mathbb{N}[x]$?

Comment: Obviously $F_2$, as I mentioned. And $F_2[x]$, and $\mathbb N[x][y]$ and so on.

Comment: @RomainS Could you explain why $\mathbb{N}[x]$ has unique factorization?

Comment: $\mathbb N[x]$ is not a semiring with unique factorization because $(x+1)(x^4+x^2+1)=(x^3+1)(x^2+x+1)$